# Xcode iPhone programming: how successfully substitue images in the code

Tags: iphone, xcode, image

Yesterday was my first time with the SDK :-) I opened in the Xcode a previously purchased code and overwrote several image files. Here is the thing: not all new images appear in the app on the simulator, this is so annoying :/ I already tried to put in place advices I had found earlier (iphone simulator - Attempting to delete an image from Xcode 4 - Stack Overflow, Image not showing in iPhone Simulator - Stack Overflow) but to no avail. I even completely erased the Xcode and installed it again, still I can see the old images which had been erased from the disk.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you done a Clean (Shift-Cmd-K) and deleted your build results from your disk? This shouldn't be necessary but it's happened to be before that I've had to do that.

Comment: Wow wow wow, you are bonito, my friend, the Clean performed with the combination provided in your answer did the trick! Thanks, Lifesaver! :-) :-) :-) Hopefully one day I will return the favour...

Comment: Hey, well, it turned out it helped only partially, i.e. the colours are correctly displayed only on the simulator - on the iPhone colours in one of the tabs are still coming from the original build (before I modified it), you can see it here: http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/5462/img0850oa.jpg What would be the solution here, please?

Comment: Yeah, this happens. The solution is often to delete EVERY trace of your app. So delete all the intermediate build files and actually delete the app from your phone, then do the clean all, then rebuild.

Comment: Hey pho0, God bless you! I will proceed asap and provide you with the outcome, thanks a million :-)

Comment: Hm.. Where can you find all the intermediate build files?

Answer (score 0):

Check your target (if you're running Xcode 4, it's on the top-left conner, next to "start/stop" button), and then check the image you just replaced is used for this target (again if you're on Xcode 4, select that image, open right view - on the top-right conner, there're three views).

Your problem could be the target you're building is using some other resources, not the one you just edited. To find out, click on your project on the left, choose the target you're building, go to "Build Phases", all resources you'll be using for this target in under "Copy Bundle Resources".